# jQuery ajax function error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery function for an Ajax request:

```
function ajax_submit(){
    var submit_val= $('#login_form').serialize();
    dest = "login.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: dest,
        data: submit_val,
        success: function(data){
            if(data=='ok'){
                $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
                                $(this).removeClass().addClass('spn_success').html("Everything ok, logging you in...").fadeTo(900,1,function(){
                location.href="index.php";
                });
                });
            }else if(data=='ko'){
                $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
                $(this).removeClass().addClass('spn_error').html("Wrong Username or password. Please, try again").fadeTo(900,1);
                $("#txtUsername").focus();
                });
            }else if(data=='problemi'){
                $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
                $(this).removeClass().addClass('spn_error').html("Could not connect. Maybe system is down for maintenance. Please, try again later.").fadeTo(900,1);
                $("#txtUsername").focus();
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The issue is that, even if login.php returns ok, ko or problemi and the variable data gets the right value it doesn't loop inside the if statement. What am I doing wrong so far?
Can anyone find my error?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: before `if(data=='ok')` run `console.log(data.length)` and post the output here

Comment: check the success data with alert or console.log outside the if  statement as well as inside the statement

Comment: What is *actually* being returned from the server?

Comment: or, better: `console.log(data)`

Comment: try this if($.trim(data)=='ok')

Comment: data retrived in the success function is ok without blanks, quotes or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by using trim()

if(data.trim()=='ok'){

Comment: don't get why but this works. Data returned by the login.php page is already without any blank space. Anyway, thanks a lot for the trick!